# is there a way to move all nan values to the bottom of my pandas data frame without sacrificing the column names and order of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code for the data frame I currently have. I am trying to move all the nans to the bottom of the columns without sacrificing the order of the values present and the column headers name.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUI1a.png) I have used the replace function to remove the nans and leave it empty space.

Here is how my data frame currently looks like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5F24.png)

Comment: Please embed your code in this question, it is generally not best practice to provide a link.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mask, it will preserve the original order of your rows.

```
nan_mask = combined_df.isna().any(axis=1)
new_combined_df = pd.concat((combined_df[~nan_mask], combined_df[nan_mask]), axis=0)
```

In case you already replaced your nans:

```
nan_mask = (combined_df == "").any(axis=1)
new_combined_df = pd.concat((combined_df[~nan_mask], combined_df[nan_mask]), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet replaced `NaN` with empty string, you can use:

(assuming your dataframe is called `df`)

```
df_new = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

If you have already replaced `NaN` with empty string, you can use:

```
df_new = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x!=''].values))
```